# Sending a header From swagger API

Tags: laravel, swagger, swagger-ui, jwt

I am using [Swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger) with Laravel 7 and I want to use jwt for authenticating the users. But when I try to authenticate users I need to send a token with the request.

This is my controller method:

```
 /**
 * Get the authenticated User.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 * 
 * @OA\Post(
 *     path="/api/auth/user",
 *     @OA\Response(response="200", description="Registering a new User."),
 *     @OA\RequestBody(
 *         @OA\MediaType(
 *             mediaType="application/json",
 *             @OA\Schema(
 *                 @OA\Property(
 *                     property="authentication",
 *                     type="string"
 *                 ),
 *                 example={"authentication": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODAwMFwvYXBpXC9hdXRoXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTU4NTUyNzA5MSwiZXhwIjoxNTg1NTMwNjkxLCJuYmYiOjE1ODU1MjcwOTEsImp0aSI6IllTNElhM0JkdGVpdmVMVlQiLCJzdWIiOjYxLCJwcnYiOiI4N2UwYWYxZWY5ZmQxNTgxMmZkZWM5NzE1M2ExNGUwYjA0NzU0NmFhIn0.GF2_8-WhgD9rIS2SjxY9D4wQzZQVhVLXsacJO1f8dg4"}
 *             )
 *         )
 *     ),
 * )
 *
 */
 public function user()
  {
     return response()->json(auth()->user());
  }
 */
```

I did it using Postman. But I want to know what is the right way of sending the token to the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, we have to do two things

1. declare a SecurityScheme on the base controller like the following

```
     * @OA\SecurityScheme(
     *    securityScheme="bearerAuth",
     *    in="header",
     *    name="bearerAuth",
     *    type="http",
     *    scheme="bearer",
     *    bearerFormat="JWT",
     * ),
```

2. use the declared SecurityScheme on the corresponding API calling as following

```
     *       security={
     *           {"bearerAuth": {}}
     *       }
```

Now, if you reload your API documentation page, will see an **Authorize** button has been added, clicking that button will open a model where you will be able to input your `token`.

**Token input view**
[image]

After authorizing using the valid token, you will be able to access the API that needs authorization. Hope this might help someone.